Construct schemes like toric varieties on manifolds
I'm reading a book about toric varieties, and some thoughts occured to me.
Toric varieties are constructed by fans which are the union of rational cones in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it possible to construct a scheme on a smooth manifold $M$?
I have two ideas. First, given a distribution $D$ on $M$, consider a tensor field $\mathcal{T}$ on $M$ which consists of contangent vectors whose values on all the vectors in $D$ is non-negative, then glue Spec($\mathbb{C}[\mathcal{T}_p]$) together, $p\in M$. Second, suppose $M$ is triangulable, consider its simplicial cochain groups $C^{*}_n$, then glue Spec($\mathbb{C}[C^{*}_n]$) together.
Sorry for my probable naive ideas.
